# Trigger touchesEnded when dragging outside the UIView

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have a UIView subclass where I handle touches using touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded.
I noticed that when I start a touch inside and then drag outside the UIView touchesEnded is not triggered, is there a way to have it called when I'm dragging outside the UIView frame?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use touchesCancelled instead.

```
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pssibly it is calling the `- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Please check [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **touchesCancelled:withEvent:**
>
> Sent to the receiver when a system event (such as a low-memory
>   warning) cancels a touch event.
>
> `- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
>
> *Parameters*
>
> **touches**
>
> ```
> A set of UITouch instances that represent the touches for the ending phase of the event represented by event. event
>
> An object representing the event to which the touches belong.
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method is invoked when the Cocoa Touch framework receives a
>   system interruption requiring cancellation of the touch event; for
>   this, it generates a UITouch object with a phase of
>   UITouchPhaseCancel. The interruption is something that might cause the
>   application to be no longer active or the view to be removed from the
>   window
>
> When an object receives a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message it
>   should clean up any state information that was established in its
>   touchesBegan:withEvent: implementation.
>
> The default implementation of this method does nothing. However
>   immediate UIKit subclasses of UIResponder, particularly UIView,
>   forward the message up the responder chain. To forward the message to
>   the next responder, send the message to super (the superclass
>   implementation); do not send the message directly to the next
>   responder. For example,
>
> **[super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];**
>
> If you override this method without calling super (a common use
>   pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch
>   events, if only as stub (empty) implementations. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

Comment: yes I know touchesCancelled but in my case is not triggered, I'm investigating possible reason why this is not happening.

Comment: no gestures, I'm also trying with pointInside or hitTest (to make the view trigger touchesEnded) but without success.

Comment: and even clipsToBounds set to YES, but no luck

Comment: is the view triggering the touches began ?

Answer (score 0):

You should still be getting `touchesMoved` in your `viewController` even you are outside of your view's frame. I would add array to your custom `UIView` which would keep touch objects that this view is assigned to and implement the following logic:

1. When you receive `touchesBegan` - add touch object to array for given `UIView` where touch coordinates match (you may have to iterate over all your subviews and match coordinates with frame to find the right one)
2. When you receive `touchesMoved` - remove touch from `UIView's` array for previous location and add it to `UIView` for current location if any
3. When you receive `touchesEnded` & `touchesCancelled` - remove touches from all `UIViews` arrays

When you remove or add touch object from your custom UIView array you may call your delegate methods (implement observer pattern) because at that point you know if it's really pressed or unpressed event. Keep in mind you may have many touch objects in one array so before calling your delegate check whether you added first object or deleted last one because that's the only case you should call your delegate.

I have implemented such solution in my last game, but instead of `UIViews` I had virtual buttons.

Comment: Interesting, I think what I want to achieve is something simpler but I cannot find how to do it